# What's the license of the Playground samples?

Tags: google-mirror-api, google-glass

I've been trying to find what license the HTML/JSON samples on the [Mirror API Playground](https://developers.google.com/glass/playground) are covered by, but I can't seem to find it. The sample projects are all covered by Apache 2.0, as well as all the client libraries. But there are no licence files for anything on the Playground. Not even the [CSS](https://mirror-api-playground.appspot.com/assets/css/base_style.css) for timeline items has a license in it.

Furthermore, there are images and text in the sample cards, as well as an iframe with extra CSS/JS which can be used to prototype timeline items.

So this is my question: Am I allowed to in any way redistribute these files? If so, where can I find the license that states the terms of redistribution? And if they currently aren't covered by any license, could they be in the future?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless otherwise noted, assume that code in the Mirror API documentation is licensed under the [Apache 2.0 license](http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0) and content under the [Creative Commons Attribution 3.0 License](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/3.0/).

I'll update the docs to clarify this.

Comment: Awesome :) Does this include the source code of the actual playground? eg. https://mirror-api-playground.appspot.com/card.html